# Append external file to head

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to load a file into the head… but also keep what is currently in the head.

At the moment… the file loads into the head, but it removes the title before doing so.

How do I keep the title in the head and load the file at the same time.

```js
$('head').load('../../external_file.html');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
  <title>Home</title>
  <!-- External File goes here -->
  <!-- I want the title to stay -->
</head>
```

Comment: I think you will have to load it in JS and append the result to `head` `$('head').append(...)`

Comment: Is "external_file.html" an HTML fragment or an HTML `document` having `<html>` and `<body>` tags?

Comment: Its a fragment.

Comment: @MonwellPartee Why do you want to load the fragment as a child of `<head>` element?

Comment: will use meta.html as a central hub

Comment: I change one… I change all

Comment: Not following what expected result is? Elements within `<head>` element are, generally, not rendered in `document`.

Comment: Its a meta.html file… that only thing in meta.html are meta tags

Comment: The current answers should resolve inquiry, yes?

Comment: correct… it should

Comment: May anyone indicate without JQuery, so using plain vanilla javascript ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you are trying to insert HTML file in the head, but try this anyway.

1. put your jquery.min.js in the footer or in the bottom part of your html not above the head.
2. you can do it via ajax(i am assume that your trying to spit out html element inside your external html file to head).

   `(function(){
           $.ajax({
               url : "../../external_file.html",
               type: "GET",
               dataType: "html",
               success : function (data) {
                   $(data).appendTo('head');
               }
           });
   })();`

   this will make an ajax request and return what ever the content of your html file 
   and append to your head.

[image]

[image]

**:update:**

okay please follow this:

1. all of your script away from head(for standard) put it somewhere bellow the your html file.
2. take away my code from .ajaxComplete(you dont need it anyway the ajaxComplete);
3. put your $('.click_explore').click() inside success function inside my code. because the current structure that causes the loop.

   ```
       (function(){
       $.ajax({
           url : "../../external_file.html",
           type: "GET",
           dataType: "html",
           success : function (data) {
               $(data).appendTo('head');
               $(".click_explore").click(function() {
                   $('body').animate({
                       scrollTop: $(".scroll_to_me").offset().top - 100
                   }, 500);
                   return false;
               });

           }
       });
   })();
   ```

I hope this help.

Comment: Its in an never ending loop

Comment: its not looping at all, it gets only once with the 'GET' request. there is no way that this could do a loop, can you show your code?

P.S Zack Sunderland is more likely to use. its simple. my answer is a long hand method.

Comment: Your code is the only one that works… It's looping because it's running along side another ajax… which is probably making it loop endlessly

Comment: the possible reason that you are getting a loop is that you might have multiple declaration of jquery CDN, check that . please provide a snippets of your code.

Comment: $( window).ajaxComplete(HTML);

Comment: ahh hmmm but i have tried zacks too and it works, ill check again.

Comment: It's probably me running 2 ajax along side each other

Comment: I'll run yours… then run the one above and it endlessly loops… and Zacks just get nullified

Comment: I see, ah maybe try changing some class or id to avoid loops(with my code),. any way i like the idea of having meta as central hub. ingenious!

Comment: Here is a link… be warned… It may crash your computer… so open the site  inspect and close the tab

Comment: I changed it to test.html… that way I can keep working on trying to fix the old one

Comment: I have update my answer please follow that. the click event should be inside the ajax success function or if you dont want it to be dependent in the  success you can put it out side ajax.

Comment: I figured it out… Thanks

Comment: Please post without JQUERY, just plain js

Answer (score 2):

Use `$.get()` instead of `$.load()` this will return the contents of the file and you can add the contents to the end of the element from there.

Below is a rough example:

```
$.get('../../external_file.html', function(response) {
        $('head').append(response);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `load` is a shortcut to entirely replace the html content, so if you want to keep the title, you will need to use a few more lines.

You could track the title and add it back after load:

```
var title = $('head title').text();
$('head').load('../../external_file.html');
$('head').prepend('<title>' + title + '</title>');
```

Or you could append the new content to what's there.

```
$.get('../../external_file.html', function(data) {
    // add error handling
    $('head').append(data);
});
```

Comment: I've tried to implement this… but it keeps overriding it

Answer (score 0):

USING PLAIN JAVASCRIPT (JS VANILLA)

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open("GET", "/yourpath/toyourfile.html", true);
ajaxInicial.onreadystatechange = function () {if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', this.responseText);}}
ajaxInicial.send();
```